# Pagina se actualiza al enviar formulario y la alerta se desaparece al instante

Tags: javascript, php, html, css3

estoy validando una alerta con sweetalert2 para preguntar si desea eliminar si o no,
el problema ocurre cuando al momento de presionar el boton de eliminar envía la accion mediante el método post y actualiza la pagina, entonces la alerta se ve pero se desaparece muy rápido y ya no se puede elegir si desea eliminar si o no. Espero me ayuden gracias.

Mi código es este

```js
function alertDelete() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      Swal.fire(
        'Deleted!',
        'Your file has been deleted.',
        'success'
      )
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="txtID_Proyects" id="txtID_Proyects" value="<?php echo $libro['id_proyectos'];  ?>" />
  <button class="icon-accion" type="submit" name="accion" value="Seleccionar"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i> Seleccionar</button>
  <button type="submit" name="accion" value="Borrar" class="icon-accion" onclick="alertDelete()  "><i class="fa-solid fa-delete-left"></i> Borrar</button>
</form>
```

Acción Borrar con PHP

```php
case "Borrar":
    $sentenciaSQL= $conexion->prepare("SELECT imagen FROM proyectos WHERE id_proyectos=:id_proyectos");
    $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':id_proyectos',$txtID_Proyects);
    $sentenciaSQL->execute();
    $libro=$sentenciaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

    if (isset($libro["imagen"]) && ($libro["imagen"] != "imagen.jgp")) {
        if (file_exists("imagenes/".$libro["imagen"])) {
            unlink("imagenes/".$libro["imagen"]);
        }
    }

    $sentenciaSQL= $conexion->prepare("DELETE  FROM proyectos WHERE id_proyectos=:id_proyectos");
    $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(':id_proyectos',$txtID_Proyects);
    $sentenciaSQL->execute();

    print "<script>window.setTimeout(function() { window.location = 'portafolio.php' }, 200);</script>";
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

@masterguru va por el camino correcto. Lo primero es cambiar el tipo del botón de "submit" a "button", de esa manera no se va a enviar el formulario automáticamente al clickearlo.

El problema es que al transformarlo en un simple botón y enviar el formulario desde JS, el valor del botón ("Borrar") no se envía.

Lo que hice (hay varias formas), fue agregar un input oculto con el valor de la *acción* a ejecutar. Por defecto lleva el valor de "Seleccionar", que es el valor que tenía el botón "submit". Al presionar el botón de borrar, y confirmada la acción, se cambia el valor de ese input por "Borrar" y luego se envía el formulario.

```js
function alertDelete() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
  }).then((result) => {
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      // Muestra el mensaje
      Swal.fire(
        'Deleted!',
        'Your file has been deleted.',
        'success'
      );
      
      // Espera 2 segundos
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        // Cambia el valor del input "accion" a "Borrar"
        document.getElementById('accion').value = 'Borrar';
        
        // Envía el formulario
        document.getElementById('form').submit();
      }, 2000);
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<form id="form" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="txtID_Proyects" id="txtID_Proyects" value="<?php echo $libro['id_proyectos']; ?>">

  <input type="hidden" id="accion" name="accion" value="Seleccionar">

  <button type="submit" class="icon-accion">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i> Seleccionar
  </button>

  <button type="button" class="icon-accion" onclick="alertDelete()">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-delete-left"></i> Borrar
  </button>
</form>
```